# Consulta unir todos los duplicados

Tags: mysql

Buenas realizo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT l.Nombre,r.CodParada, r.Nombre, h.Tipo,h.Hora,h.Periodo,h.Dias
       FROM recorrido r 
       LEFT JOIN lineas l 
            ON l.CodLinea=r.CodLinea 
       INNER JOIN horarios h 
            ON l.CodLinea=h.CodLinea 
       WHERE l.CodLinea=1 
       ORDER BY r.CodLinea,r.CodTrayecto, r.OrdenParada,h.Dias
```

la cual me devuelve la siguiente estructura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestión es que yo no quiero que se repita ya que para cada CodLinea, el Tipo,Hora,Periodo y Días son iguales, y en este caso se repite para cada Nombre, yo quiero que solo salga una vez por cada CodLinea, y no por cada Nombre,

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Necesitas un `GROUP BY`

Comment: @alanfcm muchas gracias por contestar tan rápido, el caso es que no consigo agruparlo por los campos para que me de el resultado que quiero, que es que no se repitan 9 veces los campos (tipo, hora, periodo, dias) por cada "Nombre" si no que salgan una vez solo

Comment: @Marcos, no lo que busco es sacar cada codlinea como sale, luego una sola vez cada parada, y luego una sola vez por toda la consulta el tipo hora periodo y dias

Comment: @KeTeMeTo, ¿podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el resultado que esperas obtener de la consulta? Sinceramente aún no entendí

Comment: Al final lo hize con dos consultas separadas, por un lado queria ver la linea con todas sus paradas, y tambien sus horarios pero que no se repitieran por cada parada, al final desisti y saque la lista de todas las lineas y paradas ordenadas, y por otro lado los horarios de cada linea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes agregarle la funcion Group by a los campos necesarios, esto agrupara los valores repetidos en tu consulta

ejemplo:

```
Group BY  l.Nombre,r.CodParada, r.Nombre, h.Tipo,h.Hora,h.Periodo,h.Dias
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar tan rápido, al agregar ese group by sigue dando el mismo resultado, me repite todo el rato los tipos horas periodos y dias, para cada "Nombre" y quisiera que saliese el tipo hora periodo y dias solo una vez